# Replicating Excel's PPMT Function in PHP

Tags: php, excel, finance

I want to replicate Excel's PPMT function in PHP but can't seem to get the same value. I've asked ChatGPT repeatedly and tried it out, but the values are different. I want to derive the same values in PHP as in Excel.

### Excel conditions are as follows:

```
=D2+PPMT(B7,1,($B$1+1-A7),D2)

D2 = 10000
B7 = 8%
B1 = 5
A7 = 1

Value in Excel: 8295.44
```

---

```
 =C7+PPMT(B8,1,($B$1+1-A8),C7)

 C7 = 8295.44
 B8 = 9%
 B1 = 5
 A8 = 2

 Value in Excel: 6481.48
```

---

Please help me with this.

Comment: Microsoft's own description of it here looks wrong https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/ppmt-function-c370d9e3-7749-4ca4-beea-b06c6ac95e1b Making 12 monthly payments at a twelfth of the annual rate is not equivalent to making annual payments. I suggest you just write your own.